# how do i make a variable from a column of mysql table for every row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

trying not to make a table with a ton of columns.  instead making a few columns and a ton of rows (or records).

if i did this with a ton of columns i would know how to do this, but how do you do this with multiple rows/records?

i have a table with these fields:

```
id, product_category, product_name, quantity_range, discount_amt
```

there are going to be a lot of records, but i'll just shorten it to a few rows for this question.

lets say i had these records:

```
1    Post Card    4x6    5M to 9,999      0.007
2    Post Card    4x6    10M to 14,999    0.01
3    Post Card    4x6    15M to 19,999    0.013
4    Post Card    4x6    20M to 24,999    0.015
5    Post Card    4x6    Over 25M         0.019
```

now what i want to do is make a group of variables of all the values in just the discount_amt column.

so i select everything in table like so:

```
$pricediscountquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pricing_discount") or die(mysql_error());
```

then loop through result/rows like this:

```
while($pricingdiscountrow = mysql_fetch_array( $pricediscountquery )) {
  //echo $pricingdiscountrow['product_category']." ";
  //echo $pricingdiscountrow['product_name']." ";
  //echo $pricingdiscountrow['quantity_range']." ";
  echo $pricingdiscountrow['discount_amt']." ";
  echo "<br />";
}
```

this displays all the values of the column in a single variable name.  i don't want that.  i wan't a variable for 0.007, a different variable for 0.01, a different variable for 0.013, a different variable for 0.015, and a different variable for 0.019.

how do i do that?

Comment: _"this displays all the values of the column in a single variable name"_: This is where you lost me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an array:

```
$i=0;
while($pricingdiscountrow = mysql_fetch_array( $pricediscountquery )) 
$myarray[$i++]=$pricingdiscountrow['discount_amt'];
```

Comment: Why not just `$myarray[]=...`, πατρίδα?

Comment: nai. every loop of the while is a row. you have to take one value from each row and store it in the array. so i use an index for the different rows according to the number of the row. Maybe redundant but the clue here is to use an array.

Comment: The clue is ok. And it works either way. I just thought using yet another variable would be (semantically, above all) redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable variable. It's essentially setting one variable to equal something:

```
$foo = 'bar';
```

Then using the value of that variable to set as the name for the next variable:

```
$$foo = 'dog';
echo $bar; // would return 'dog';
```

However, it would be easier to use an associative array.

```
$data = array();
while() {
    $data[$variableName] = $pricingdiscountrow['discount_amt'];
};
```